# How to create dynamic select elements using livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to add a new `select` input every time a previous `select` was changed, but when i try to add more elements to a public attribute on components class i got the error:

> Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [product-categories] component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests.

The class

```
class Category extends Component {
    public array $categories = [];

    public function edit($category) {
        $this->state = $category;
        $this->categories[] = []; // more info from an api
    }

    public function choose($category) {
        $this->categories[] = []; // more info from an api
    }
}
```

The template:

```
@if($categories)
    @foreach($categories as $cat)
        <label class="text-gray-700" for="category">
            Category:
        <select wire:change="choose($event.target.value)" id="animals" class="w-full block w-52 py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500" name="animals">
            <option disabled selected >
                Selecione...
            </option>
            @foreach($cat as $c)
                <option value="{{ $c->getId() }}" wire:key="{{ $c->getId() }}">{{ $c->getName() }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </label>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

It is possible do create new `select` inputs dynamicaly?

Comment: ```@foreach($cat as $c)
                <option value="{{ $category->getId() }}" wire:key="{{ $category->getId() }}">{{ $category->getName() }}</option>
            @endforeach``` This is correct?

Comment: sorry @Prospero, it was a typo

Comment: Have a look at this video [Livewire: 3-Level Dependent Dropdowns - Edit Form Values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfSjRcudZVA)

Comment: @Digvijay it does not work as well, if i try to use `wire:model` the error is the same

Comment: I've open a issue on github https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2677